# My installation path is different with the documentation path, why?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, software-installation, paths

Recently I'm installing OpenVino from scratch following this documentation : [Install Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO™ toolkit for Linux*](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_linux.html) . Now after several steps, I realized that the output path specified in the documentation is different with the actual path in my machine after installation. For example :

- Documentation :

  ```
  /home/<user>/openvino_models/models/FP32/classification/squeezenet/1.1/caffe/squeezenet1.1.caffemodel
  ```
- Mine :

  ```
  /home/raisa/openvino_models/models/public/squeezenet1.1/squeezenet1.1.caffemodel
  ```

Eventhough it's in different path, the file is there and I can link it properly (for now). I'm afraid in the future this path inconsistency will cause trouble in my program, for example I'm missing about 4 directories here compared to the documentation (**FP32**, **Classification**, **Squeezenet** and **Caffe**) that I don't know if they're gonna be necessary in the future or not.

Also, for environment variable I need to either run this script everytime I execute my program, or specify it in .bashrc.

- Documentation :

  ```
  source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
  ```

Now, of course I can't specify that path in my .bashrc since I don't even have that path in my machine, so I put the path that I have in in my machine in .bashrc :

- Mine

  ```
  source /opt/intel/openvino_2019.3.376/bin/setupvars.sh
  ```

But it doesn't work. My environment is error. Even if I put the path from the documentation in .bashrc, my environment is still error. However, if I just run the script (from the documentation) right before I execute the program, it worked, eventhough I don't even have that path. How is that possible ?

I want to understand and fix this. When something like this happen, does that mean my installation is corrupt ? Do I need to reinstall ? How did this happen ?

Comment: It is likely that the path is called in more than one place. I would recommend instead of changing the code that supplements the download, rename the folder you downloaded to not have the `_2019.3.376` section.

Comment: You can add a link to match the documentation, which allows installation of a newer release into it's own directory, which you can use for testing, until you switch the link to the new one.